# kafka KRaft cluster + Metadata storage

Tags: apache-kafka

we installed successfully Kafka Kraft cluster that include 3 controllers machines and 3 broker machines as the following

[image]

all machines with  RHEL 8.x version

as we understand the folder - `__cluster_metadata-0`, is accumulates all the metadata changes of the cluster and its make sense that its related to controller cluster machines

but when we checked the brokers machines we found that this folder - `__cluster_metadata-0`
also exist on each of the broker machines

example

```
ls -1 /data/kafka/

Output:
bootstrap.checkpoint
__cluster_metadata-0
meta.properties

ls -1 __cluster_metadata-0/

Output:
00000000000000000000.index
00000000000000000000.log
00000000000000000000.timeindex
00000000000000000159.snapshot
00000000000000000288.snapshot
00000000000000000459.snapshot
00000000000000000630.snapshot
00000000000000000827.snapshot
00000000000000001032.snapshot
00000000000000001257.snapshot
00000000000000001419.snapshot
00000000000000001585.snapshot
leader-epoch-checkpoint
partition.metadata
quorum-state
```

so why Kafka architecture design reburied the metadata folder - `__cluster_metadata-0` also on brokers machine ?

about the controllers machines its obvious that meta data folder - `__cluster_metadata-0` should be part of controller machines but not clear why meta data folder exist also on brokers machines ?

another point
when we run topic describes as the following

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092 --describe
```

this topic - `__cluster_metadata-0` , not printed from described output
so this topic isn't regular topic as the others

related links - https://redpanda.com/guides/kafka-tutorial/kafka-without-zookeeper

Comment: It's a regular Kafka topic, so it exists on the data-plane as well... btw: you can stop tagging linux since this same behavour would happen on any other OS when running Kafka.

Comment: BTW if you run for example kafka topic descried then from the output you not see this topic , so its not pure  topic like the others ( for example you can create any topic then run kafka topic described and you see this topic but __cluster_metadata-0 is no part of topics list

Comment: `kafka-topics` has an `--exclude-internal` flag, meaning there are ways to hide output from that list...

Comment: you means the flag "--exclude-internal" is inside as default ?  , if so how to disable this flag ?

Comment: No, it's not the default. I'm just saying that if any topic isn't shown in the list/describe command, doesn't mean it's not a topic. Structurally, it has logs, indexes and timestamps, and partitions... It is a topic. It might only be used by controllers, but that doesn't mean data won't be stored in the brokers. Maybe you can review KIP500 for the design of Kraft mode